# Is there any benefit to use `src` sub-folder inside `lib` folder

Tags: flutter, dart

When I'm trying to develop a flutter **app (not a package, etc)**, Is there any benefit to create all application files and folders in `src` sub-folder inside `lib` folder?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question is tagged as Flutter but should probably also have the Dart flag as Dart is the language used by Flutter.  According to [Dart Organising a library Package](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages), the convention of  putting code under lib/src is called a "convention" and the purpose is to separate the library's public code from private implementation code.

There is a second reason further down that states:

> Tip for web apps: For the best performance when developing with dartdevc, put implementation files under /lib/src, instead of elsewhere under /lib. Also, avoid imports of package:package_name/src/....

As the dartdevc compiler is used by flutter at development time in debug mode (see [Flutter Debug Build mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes#debug)), there does appear to be a design-time speed advantage with hot reload if you use the lib/src structure rather than just lib.  Please note a different compiler is used for release - dart2js - so there is no advantage in this scenario (see the same link above).

A similar historical discussion on the above points can be found on the dart language github here: [Recommendations for /lib/src vs. /lib](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/1163#issuecomment-422957587)

Comment: does that mean that it's better to move all files with .dart extension into the src folder (including the dart files that represent widgets and helpers) ?

Comment: As per what I was trained to do at the time, the answer would have been yes.  This is a couple of years old now and I haven't been following the dart specification.  I've seen most developers ignore this structure and with current compiler speeds, etc. I think it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lib/src` actually makes sense only for package writing. We put everything that can be imported by the user of the package in the `lib` and all private libraries inside `src`.

On the other side when we are used to such a convention while writing packages why not to continue use it when writing apps?

The only confusing thing is a `main.dart` file. The package does not have it, but the application does. `Main.dart` is obviously a source file, but should be placed in the `lib` folder.

Considering the above it is kinda should be a matter of developer/team choice.

I do it with src:

```
     lib
        /main.dart
        /src
            /lib_1.dart
            /lib_2.dart
```

Answer (score -1):

Using directories is just a way to organize your resources/files.

In the current scenario it is just to separate source files from the rest.

The main benefit of doing so is that if you open your project after a month/year for some reason then those directory names will help you to recollect things faster.

Other benefits include:

1. Your team-mates (if any) shall be able to understand your project structure faster. Imagine if you just piled up everything in just one directory how difficult things could have got for them.
2. Duplicate files can be stored within the same `lib` file.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about `src` inside `lib`. Some programmers move all of their code inside `src` folder. I heard about the benefits that it has for package developing and web developing with dart and I'm interested to know if there is any benefits to also use it in flutter app developing.

Comment: There are no exclusive benefits of specifically for having a separate 'src' folder in the 'lib' directory of your project apart from the once mentioned above.

Comment: Let me know if there is any specific reasoning which is makes you think that having a different 'src' folder in 'lib' directory will have any other exclusive benefits apart from the once mentioned above.

Comment: It's like asking why do we use variable names for reference when we can use memory addresses instead